# Update My Create React App Template versions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

So I have built my own template that when I generate a CRA that I use that has things like tailwind and such set up. For normal applications I can usually use `npx npm-check-updates -u` and it updated all my dependencies. The issue with the templates, is the package.json file is named `template.json`. Is there a utility that can update those things in there like it does with the `package.json`?